# How can I have column E copy its data into the right column based on the initials in column M?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet that will auto time stamp column N when my technicians enter their initials into column M. The second thing I would like the spreadsheet to do is, when I enter the hours (example: 1.8) into column E "HRS.", have the spreadsheet put the HRS. into the correct Technicians column, based on the initials entered in column M "Tech Up". Examples:

```
if E4=1.8 it would put 1.8 into G4 because M4=AB

if E6=3.2 it would put 3.2 into J6 because M6=JW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? The ranges are different here but the logic is the same - each cell in your range gets a formula like this (this is cell `B2` in the screenshot):

```
=IF($E2=B$1,$A2,"")
```

Which checks to see if the value in the `Name` column is equal to the column heading of the current cell; if so, it adds the value you put in the `HRS` column, and if not, it stays blank.

[image]

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: WOOT!!! That is exactly what i was looking for!!! Thx

Comment: @myanda No prob, happy it helps!